# reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'

Tags: c++, vector

This is leetcode 26. Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appear only once and return the new length. An example is given `nums = [1,1,2]`, the function should return `[1,2]`.

Below is my code. I delete all the other duplicates, just leave one of them. However I always got an error of `reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'` when submitting. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this!

```
class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < nums.size() - 1) {
            if (nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) {
                nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
            } 
            else i++;
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can't duplicate. https://ideone.com/ppuRg5.

Comment: Show a complete program that gives the error message.

Comment: @RSahu Good example of a lacking test suite ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`vector<T>::size()` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. Let's say the vector passed in is empty and therefore the vector's length is 0. `nums.size() - 1` will cause integer underflow and you will actually be comparing `0` with a very large positive number. This will evaluate to true causing the loop to run and `i` going pass the array bounds.

To fix this you can cast `nums.size()` to `int` preemptively or store the size in an integer variable and compare with that.

Comment: Or change it to `while (i + 1 < nums.size())`. This will work as long as `nums.size()` is not `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 8):

The function, as posted, works fine for a vector whose elements are `[1 1 2]`. See https://ideone.com/ppuRg5.

However, one problem I see in your function is that if you pass it an empty vector, it's going to run into problems.

```
while(i < nums.size() - 1)
```

will be a problem when `nums` is empty. You can preemptively avoid that problem by returning from the function immediately if you find that it is an empty vector.

Also, use an unsigned type for `i` to avoid compiler warnings about comparing signed and unsigned types.

```
int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
   if ( nums.empty() )
   {
      return 0;
   }

   unsigned int i = 0;
   while(i < nums.size() - 1) {
      if (nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) {
         nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
      } 
      else i++;
   }
   return nums.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, but it would be more efficient solution to the problem if you didn't have to resize your vector each time you find a duplicate. Just to give you an idea, you could have two iterators i and j, i keeping the index of the last unique element of your solution vector and j iterating through the vector. When j points to a value not in the first i elements, copy that to v[i]. And once you are done, delete everything from the j-th place onwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason of this error message was segmentation fault.

**Example**
For empty input:

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) { 
    auto start = strs[0];
```

It works OK, when I add check for empty input

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
        if (strs.size() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
    auto start = strs[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
  public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector < int > & nums) {
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
                nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out that instead of comparing or operating `num.size()` with any integer directly
First store `int n=num.size();` and then compare it like `if(num=n-2)`.